# Calculating NDWI in Erdas IMAGINE 2014

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, modis, digital-image-processing

I'm using MOD09GQ product of MODIS to calculate vegetation indices in Erdas 2014, and I was able to extract NDVI using Erdas Model Builder.

What is the formula I should use in model builder for calculating Normalized Difference Water Index (NDWI) in Erdas? Do i need to download another products of MODIS for computing NDWI?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be just one question asked per question.  There is an **edit** button beneath your question that you can use to remove all but your most important question from this one.

Answer (score 3):

the original (GAO 1996) NDWI is based reflectance for the wavelength of 0.86 (NIR) and 1.24 µm (SWIR). This corresponds to bands 2 and 5 if you use MODIS. The equation for MODIS is thus (b2-b5)/(b2+b5).

There are derived equation with other SWIR bands (e.g. for Landsat OLI the SWIR is around 1.6 µm), as well as NDWI2 (Mc Feeters 1996) which uses green (band 4 of MODIS) and NIR if you don't have SWIR bands.

MOD09GQ only provides bands for the red and NIR (the one you need for NDVI), but not the SWIR that is necessary for NDWI. Therefore you should use another product that includes band 5, such as [MOD09GA](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod09ga). Note that the resolution of band 5 is 500 m, and so is MOD09GA.